# Wordpress (CMS) - Change wording in admin backend

Tags: wordpress, content-management-system

I've tailored Wordpress into a CMS and there's some slight area's that I'm not quite happy with in terms of the wording.

E.g The page attributes area on the right when editing a page, is it possible to change the wording of "Parent", "Template" and "Order" and also add a little bit of help text.

The titles and help is all a bit techy, a lot of the people that will be using the CMS will be very basic users.

Ideally I'd like a plugin to make things a bit easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I've yet to see any ability to fully customize the default backend (without hacking core). This is one area that still bothers me about WP, especially when custom themes and forms for the admin feature are so well implemented in other systems like Drupal and Expression Engine.

With WP 3.x there are some hooks (filters) for some of the admin panel. A quick google will reveal instructions on a variety of ways.

http://www.thinkoomph.com/thinking/2010-06/customizing-wordpress-admin/

Check out the 'White Label' plugin (> 2.8)
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/white-label-cms/

Comment: I tried that one too, doesn't seem like there's anything quite out there to put some help into the actual admin.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to change the relevant admin pages in the backend.

Or just an idea, create a new localization for the changes you wish to see, as most text in the backend are output using the localization function.

Comment: I was really hoping for a plugin as it makes things a bit easier. Also a team member may need to change things as well and they're not quite techy enough to be going through the admin files. I've had a quick look for a plugin but can't see one, has anyone come across one?

Comment: I have looked at the source code for the admin panel (back in WP 2.9), and the panel's text are generated without any hooks. (I personally have tweaked the phrasings of the menu, just not the post page). I believe it can't be done.

Comment: I would've thought there's a plugin. The wording's all a bit techy so and adding some kind of help is kind of essential.

Comment: That's a great idea, avoids core-hacking. I don't think adding a localization would be that hard...perhaps someone could write a plugin that does this. You could use something like this: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/codestyling-localization/screenshots/